# how to take screenshot and save image in Selenium IDE

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, ide, command, line

I am using selenium IDE for Auto Task with chrome browser.
I would like to know how to take screenshot and save image seleniumIDE.
CaptureEntirePageScreen commad is not found in selenium IDE .Please Help Me.
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

i am using this method to take a screenshot

```
public static void getScreenshot(WebDriver driver){
File screenshot=((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
String currentLocation=
System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/main/java/screenshots/";
//but you can put  your location
    try {
        FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot,
                new File(currentLocation + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png"));
    }catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("The screenshot was not taken");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```